# Disabling data detectors for a specific HTML element in a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

Does anyone know if it's possible to disable the data detectors for phone numbers, email addresses etc in a UIWebView, for specific HTML elements only?

I'd like the detectors to be active for most of the content loaded into the UIWebView, but disable it in certain areas.

If this is possible, I'm assuming it would be achieved by using an HTML attribute in the loaded content (rather than setting some sort of UIWebView property), e.g.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1 datadetectors="off">Header text with number 9123 3456</h1>
    <p>Body text with number 9872 4567</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this example, the number in the <p> would be detected as a phone number due to setting `webview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll`, whereas the number in the <h1> would not.

Comment: I have the same problem it looks like a bug/unfinished feature in the SDK to me! I only have intellisense for disabling number detection. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can put the attribute

```
x-apple-data-detectors="false"
```

but unfortunately this seems to work only for  tags.
I ended up using this solution:

```
<a href="#" x-apple-data-detectors="false">666-777-777</a>
```

besides disabling the telephone numbers "detection", this also prevents adresses and other detection to run.

Comment: I had a container `<div>` with two `<div>`'s in it. One floating left and the other floating right. Both have numbers in them which leads the data detector to convert both numbers into `<a>` tags! Putting this in the floating `<div>`'s or the surrounding unfortunately didn't help.

Answer (score 9):

you should use `<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">`

Hope it helps

Comment: Yeah, it's helpful to apply all the project

Comment: Is there a way to re-enable this for certain elements? So most of the page has it disabled but you *know* that a certain element contains a telephone number and you still want *that* one to be a tappable element which makes a phone call?

Comment: I think the bet way is to made it backend and the send to the client the correct meta

Answer (score 1):

If you control the web content you can use jscript (via jquery) to write your own data detectors. If you don't control the content you could insert and execute the jscript using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: once webViewDidFinishLoad: is called.

Answer (score 1):

In WKWebView Disable all Data Detector Types in Attributes inspector. This will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Since an "a" tag will be inserted for you with the x-apple-data-detectors in it, you could write the tag yourself with  x-apple-data-detectors set to false.

Original code:

```
<div class="my_time">17:02</div>
```

will be transformed to:

```
<div class="my_time">
<a href="x-apple-data-detectors://1" dir="ltr" 
   x-apple-data-detectors="true" 
   x-apple-data-detectors-type="calendar-event" 
   x-apple-data-detectors-result="1" 
   style="color: rgb(169, 169, 169); 
   text-decoration-color: rgba(169, 169, 169, 0.258824);">14:18
</a>
</div>
```

You can prevent this by writing your code as following...

```
<div class="my_time">
  <a x-apple-data-detectors="false" style="text-decoration: none">17:02</a> 
</div>
```