# Disable telephone anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, anchor

I'm developing a web application using PhoneGap that will be distributed to several mobile OS including iOS.

When I generate the application to iOS the numeric values with at least 7 digits are modified to telephone anchors, in order to "fix" this I've attached the following event handler:

```
$( 'a[href^="tel"]' ).live( 'click', function() {
    return false;
});
```

This code works fine except when I use jQuery Mobile, any idea why?

Answer (score 6):

Try to add this to your header

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

See [How to disable phone number linking in Mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari)

Comment: That works fine on Safari browser but doesn't work on PhoneGap application since it uses WebView.

Comment: @Diogo instead, see http://solutions.michaelbrooks.ca/2011/02/09/disable-telephone-detection-in-phonegap-ios/

Comment: I'm not understanding the solution, it requires that I build the application in XCode? I'm using PhoneGap Build and I would like to continue to use it :)

Comment: @Diogo try this `<a href="#" x-apple-data=detectors="false">666-777-777</a>` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5394268/744255)

Comment: That works but I was looking for a more generic solution because I'm receiving dynamic information from WS.

Comment: For generic way, use XCode =D

Answer (score 0):

it actually works well for me on PhoneGap as well.